# unable to start postgresql 10, it raise "Permission denied"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, odoo-10, postgresql-10

i am using ubuntu 18 and postresql 10, all works fine until i did following command

> sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp

after this i did a lot to start but fail to do, after giving following statement;

```
postgres@abc:~$/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
```

it raise;

> pg_ctl: PID file "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postmaster.pid" does not
> exist Is server running? starting server anyway waiting for server to
> start....2021-06-22 14:54:08.120 PKT [2542] FATAL:  could not access
> private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": **Permission
> denied** 2021-06-22 14:54:08.121 PKT [2542] LOG:  database system is
> shut down  stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start server Examine the
> log output.

when i did;

> postgres@abc:~$ pg_lsclusters

down message appears

> Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
> 10  main    5432 **down**   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
> /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log

statement

```
abc@abc$ systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service raise
```

> ● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main Loaded:
> loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor
> preset: enabled) Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Tue
> 2021-06-22 16:17:38 PKT; 5min ago Process: 546
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main
> start (code=exited, status=1

> when i
> abc@abc$ sudo journalctl -xe

it raise ;

```
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox postgresql@10-main[4053]: pg_ctl: could not start server
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox postgresql@10-main[4053]: Examine the log output.
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory

Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql@10-main.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit postgresql@10-main.service has failed.
```

i also run these but no luck!

> $ sudo chown root:ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key $
> sudo chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

appreciated if anyone can assist.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the file permissions? I doubt there is a connection with the firewall.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  i did this but no luck; #set user to group back with
sudo gpasswd -a postgres ssl-cert

# Fix ownership and mode
sudo chown root:ssl-cert  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

# now postgresql starts! (and install command doesn't fail anymore)
sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: statement abc@abc$ systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service raise                        
● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Tue 2021-06-22 16:17:38 PKT; 5min ago
  Process: 546 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main start (code=exited, status=1

Comment: Please add the information in your comments as updates to your question. Also why use restart not just start? Also why not use `pg_ctlcluster 10 main start`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i did but no luck, raise same permission denied error (as mention in question)

Comment: What was this, '# now postgresql starts! ', referring to?

Comment: just comments, attached with command (as copy and past  as i did from this url https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432)

Comment: when i abc@abc$ sudo journalctl -xe
it raise ;
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox postgresql@10-main[4053]: pg_ctl: could not start server
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox postgresql@10-main[4053]: Examine the log output.
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Jun 25 09:22:48 odoo10-VirtualBox systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.

Comment: also run these but no luck!.     $ sudo chown root:ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
$ sudo chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key